# JavaCV & FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever : DuplicateFileException

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, javacv

In my Android project I use JavaCV and I also need FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever to retrieve frame at a given position :

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv-platform', version: '1.3.3'
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '2.4.11-0.11', classifier: 'android-arm'
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '2.4.11-0.11', classifier: 'android-x86'
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '2.6.1-0.11', classifier: 'android-arm'
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '2.6.1-0.11', classifier: 'android-x86'
    compile 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever:1.0.14'
    ...
}
```

On gradle compilation it fail with DuplicateFileException error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK lib/x86/libavcodec.so
    File1: C:\Users\pingu\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets\ffmpeg\3.2.1-1.3\65a0880fd927fe901cead47b9c4be9ae76a28764\ffmpeg-3.2.1-1.3-android-x86.jar
    File2: C:\Users\pingu\.android\build-cache\957befefe8a63ddc13213dcddf7f709338e00edc\output\jni
```

Is there a way to both have this libs in my android app? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Following procedure works for me.

First add these lines to your **build.gradle** file :

```
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'lib/x86/libavcodec.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/x86/libavformat.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/x86/libavutil.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/x86/libswscale.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi/libavcodec.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi/libavformat.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi/libavutil.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi/libswscale.so'
    ...
}
```

Then compilation seems to be ok, but getting an error at runtime :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: [...] couldn't find "libjniopencv_core.so"
```

To fix it :

- Create folders **app/src/main/jniLibs/{arm, armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86}**
- extract ***.so** file from **opencv-3.2.0-1.3-android-x86.jar** to **app/src/main/jniLibs/x86**
- extract ***.so** file from **opencv-3.2.0-1.3-android-arm.jar** to **app/src/main/jniLibs/{arm, armeabi, armeabi-v7a}**

Then rebuild project